# Parameters ignored in call()

Tags: python, python-2.5

I am trying to call `ssh` from a Python program but it seems to be ignoring the arguments.

This is the Python program:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, call

vm_name = 'vmName with-space'
vm_host = 'user@192.168.21.230'

def ssh_prefix_list(host=None):
    if host:
        # return ["ssh", "-v", "-v", "-v", host]
        return ["scripts/ssh_wrapper", "-v", "-v", "-v", host]
    else:
        return []

def start(vm_name, vm_host=None):  # vm_host defaults to None
    print "vm_host = ", vm_host
    vbm_args = ssh_prefix_list(vm_host) + ["VBoxManage", "startvm", vm_name]
    print vbm_args
    return call(vbm_args, shell=True)

start(vm_name, vm_host)
```

The wrapper prints the number of arguments, their values, and calls ssh.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo Number of arguments: $#
echo ssh arguments: "$@"
ssh "$@"
```

This is the output.

```
$ scripts/vm_test.py
vm_host =  stephen@192.168.21.230
['scripts/ssh_wrapper', '-v', '-v', '-v', 'stephen@192.168.21.230', 'VBoxManage', 'startvm', 'atp-systest Clone']
Number of arguments: 0
ssh arguments:
usage: ssh [-1246AaCfgKkMNnqsTtVvXxY] [-b bind_address] [-c cipher_spec]
           [-D [bind_address:]port] [-e escape_char] [-F configfile]
           [-i identity_file] [-L [bind_address:]port:host:hostport]
           [-l login_name] [-m mac_spec] [-O ctl_cmd] [-o option] [-p port]
           [-R [bind_address:]port:host:hostport] [-S ctl_path]
           [-w local_tun[:remote_tun]] [user@]hostname [command]
```

This is on Python 2.5.

Comment: Half-joking answer: try upgrading Python and maybe the problem will go away. :-)

Comment: We'd love to upgrade Python but we are on very old version of Ubuntu and there are many dependencies on it.  We're working on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using `shell=True` , you need to pass in a string, not a list of arguments. Try -

```
return call(' '.join(vbm_args), shell=True)
```

Also, you should consider constructing the string from start, rather than list.

When you pass a list to `call()` or `Popen()` with `shell=True` , only the first element in the list is actually called , and that is the reason you are seeing the wrapper called with 0 arguments.

You should also try first without using `shell=True` , since its a security hazard, as clearly stated in the [documentation of subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module) -

> Using `shell=True` can be a security hazard. See the warning under [Frequently Used Arguments](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments) for details.

Comment: OP may also want to consider not using `shell=True` in the first place, since this command doesn't look like it needs a shell anyway (it has a shebang).

Comment: Correct, added that to the answer, with link to documentation. Thank you.

Comment: Removing `shell=True` fixed the problem.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be it:

```
prefix_list = ssh_prefix_list(vm_host)
prefix_list.append(["VBoxManage startvm %s" % vm_name])
```

however I would strongly recommend using [paramiko](http://www.paramiko.org/) - it makes things much easier.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `call` with `shell=True`, you need to pass a single string, not an array of strings.  So:

```
call("scripts/ssh_wrapper -v -v -v "+host+" VBoxManage startvm "+vmname)
```